# How to make delete endpoint in phabricator?

Tags: php, endpoint, phabricator

sorry before i am a newbie person to use  [phabricator](https://github.com/phacility/phabricator/tree/master/src/applications/conpherence) and i have a task to make a delete endpoint to delete transaction comment.

I've tried to make the same as deleting the flag, but still not working.

```
$this->attachHandleToFlag($flag, $request->getUser());
$ret = $this->buildFlagInfoDictionary($flag);
$flag->delete();
return $ret;
```

do i can make a delete endpoint for transaction comment? how i do that?